# Regex getting text inside

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have been trying to grab a first location name inside the sentences. The desired location name will exactly starts at the 2nd capital of the first sentence and then precisely end before the first dot(.)

Example:

```
 It is located at Supreme Court. Follow by some other text. 
                  ^           ^
```

Desired out put

> Supreme Court

Sorry I can't show you a piece of code that I've got so far. After an hour of trying, I got nothing in concrete.

If you show the code example in Ruby would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which bit did you have difficulty with? Matching capital letters, matching a dot, or providing the desired output once you made the match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex :

```
regexp = /^.*?[A-Z].*?([A-Z].*?)\./
match = regexp.match(subject)
if match
    match = match[1]
else
    match = ""
end
```

Will produce : `Supreme Court`

I start from the start of the string matching the first capital while ignoring everyhting else. I then match the 2nd capital and save the result into backreference 1 until the first dot.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
irb(main):001:0> location = "It is located at Supreme Court. Follow by some other text."
=> "It is located at Supreme Court. Follow by some other text."
irb(main):002:0> location.match(/[^A-Za-z][\bA-Z][\w\s]*\./)
=> #<MatchData "Supreme Court.">
```

Comment: OP asks to match everything from 2nd capital to the end of the sentence.  Your regex assumes there are just two words.

Comment: Edited it a little, I think it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'It is located at Supreme Court. Follow by some other text.'
m = s.match /[A-Z][^A-Z]+([A-Z][^\.]+)/
result = m[1] #Supreme Court
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = 'It is located at Supreme Court. Follow by some other text.'
/[A-Z].+?([A-Z].*)\..+?/.match(s)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there's no space at the beginning of the string, therefore it looks for the first capital letter that comes right after a space and grabs anything until the first period it finds.

```
str = "It is located at Supreme Court. Follow by some other text."
m = str.match(/\s([A-Z].*?)\./)
location = m.nil? ? "" : m[1] #just in case there's no match

p location #=> Supreme Court
```